# How to put an image on top of a carousel slider

Tags: html, css

On the html code below I just created a carousel with four images. Before the images of the carousel I also have a container with another image which I would like to keep fixed on top of the carousel images.

```
    <div class="container-fluid hero-slide">
        <div class="row">


            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                  <!-- Indicators -->
                  <ol class="carousel-indicators">

                  <div class="container">
                    <div class="caption">
                     <img src="acacia-house-logo.png" alt="">
                   </div>
                 </div>

                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                  </ol>

                  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                  <div class="carousel-inner" >
                    <div class="item active">
                      <img src="slide2.jpg" id="item" alt="Chania">
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                      <img src="slider-1.png" id="item" alt="Chania">
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                      <img src="slider-2.png" id="item" alt="Flower">
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                      <img src="slider-3.png" id="item" alt="Flower">
                    </div>
                  </div>                  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    .caption{
       margin:15%;
    }
```

How do I play around with the image so that finally I can place them more to the left?
Another problem is that: the image is now in the middle of the carousel and it moves as the images from the carousel change.

Its basically the same as the following website displays
http://www.acaciahouse.co.za/

Comment: Why don't you get the 'container with another image' outside the carousel part ??

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

You have the overlay inside the indicator buttons. Move it just under the top container of the carousel.

Then, you must style the overlay image to be `position:absolute`, so that it can overlay the slides. A bit of positioning, use z-index to put the overlay image on top of the slides, add a bit of opacity (transparency) and voila! *See the jsFiddle at the bottom*

```css
.carousel-inner img{width:94%;height:200px;}
.overpic{position:absolute;top:10%;left:20%;opacity:0.5;z-index:2;}
 .overpic img{width:250px;height:300px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid hero-slide">
 <div class="overpic">
   <div class="caption">
   <img src="http://placeimg.com/200/200/nature" alt="">
   </div>
 </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200" id="item" alt="Chania">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200" id="item" alt="Chania">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200" id="item" alt="Flower">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200" id="item" alt="Flower">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*For some reason the stack snippet is not running Bootstrap correctly, so check out this jsFiddle:*

<kbd>[**jsFiddle example**](https://jsfiddle.net/qt79v98L/)</kbd>

---

*Answering your Questions:*

(1) How do I play around with the image so that finally I can place them more to the left?

*That is a combination of `position:absolute` and using `left:nn%` and `top:nn%`. Note that the measurements do not need to be in percent - you can use px, em, vh, etc.*

(2) Another problem is that: the image is now in the middle of the carousel and it moves as the images from the carousel change.

*`position:absolute` and correct placement of the overlay image div solves this*